# gem install json -v 1.7.3 gives 'Please update your PATH to include build tools'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, json, windows-8, build-tools

When I run:

```
rails new blog
```

I get:

```
Installing json (1.7.3)
Gem::InstallError: The 'json' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
An error occurred while installing json (1.7.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run:

```
gem install json -v 1.7.3
```

I get:

```
Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

I'm using Windows 8.  I do have `c:\ruby193\bin` in my path.  What do I do to remedy these errors?

Answer (score 208, accepted):

Make sure you install the devkit (ticking the checkboxes that will update the path) :
You might need to reinstall ruby too.

**Install the DevKit**

Download Development Kit from here http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/

DevKit url at this time For use with Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3: [DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2](https://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe)

For use with Ruby 2.0 and above (32bits version only):
[DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2](http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe)

For use with Ruby 2.0 and above (x64 - 64bits only)
[DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2](http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe)

Follow instructions [here](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit).

Or short instructions :

> Unzip the zip
>
> open command-line and go to unzipped folder
>
> ruby dk.rb init
>
> ruby dk.rb install
>
> gem install rdiscount --platform=ruby

Comment: +1 for link `git clone git://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller.git`
`cd rubyinstaller`
`rake devkit sfx=1` worked for me

Comment: Thanks, have my upvote! Worked on Windows 8.1 64-bit using Ruby 2.2 64-bit.

Answer (score 4):

sometimes when you run the `ruby dk.rb init` you got an error like this

[image: Ruby Error]

for fixing this problem you have to change the encoding of the command prompt windows .
to do this type `chcp 1256`
and you will receive this message : Active code page: 1256

now you can run that command without problem .

good luck .

Answer (score 3):

If you know that you have the proper DevKit installed (eg: via [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/ruby2.devkit)), then you simply need to run the included script to set up environment variables.

In cmd:

```
C:\> d:\path\to\DevKit2\devkitvars.bat
```

In PowerShell:

```
PS> . d:\path\to\DevKit2\devkitvars.ps1
```

These scripts will set up the correct paths in your current command window.

Comment: Thanks, I ran `db.rb init` and `install`, but I was missing this step.

Answer (score 1):

#### Delete the old `DevKit folder` before you `extract` the new one which you will download from one of the following `links`, based on your `configuration`:

DevKit url at this time For use with Ruby 1.8.7 and 1.9.3: https://github.com/downloads/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe

For use with Ruby 2.0 and above (32bits version only): http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-mingw64-32-4.7.2-20130224-1151-sfx.exe2

For use with Ruby 2.0 and above (x64 - 64bits only) http://dl.bintray.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx.exe3