# using guard with the guard/phpunit plugin

Tags: phpunit, laravel-4, guard

When I run guard init I get an error

```
app>guard init
14:56:14 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/phpunit' or '~/.guard/templates/phpunit
' or find class Guard::Phpunit
```

the guard file is created but its empty. It should contain this code

```
guard 'phpunit', :cli => 'colors' do
watch(%r{^.+Test.php$})
end
```

but when I edit the file manually to include it and run guard I get

```
app>guard
14:59:32 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/phpunit' or find class Guard::Phpunit
14:59:32 - ERROR - C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb
:1637:in `raise_if_conflicts'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:746:in `acti
vate'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:212:in `rescue in try_acti
vate'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:209:in `try_activate'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `resc
ue in require'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `requ
ire'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:1
00:in `plugin_class'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:5
7:in `initialize_plugin'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard.rb:167:in `add_p
lugin'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/dsl.rb:175:in `b
lock in guard'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/dsl.rb:173:in `e
ach'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/dsl.rb:173:in `g
uard'
> [#] C:/Users/Mark/Dropbox/www/trainercompare/app/Guardfile:4:in `_instance_eva
l_guardfile'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/guardfile/evalua
tor.rb:121:in `instance_eval'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/guardfile/evalua
tor.rb:121:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/guardfile/evalua
tor.rb:37:in `evaluate_guardfile'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/setuper.rb:144:i
n `evaluate_guardfile'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/setuper.rb:62:in
 `setup'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/commander.rb:24:
in `start'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/cli.rb:96:in `st
art'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in
`run'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:120
:in `invoke_command'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in `dispat
ch'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:439:in `s
tart'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/bin/guard:6:in `<top (requ
ired)>'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/bin/guard:23:in `load'
> [#] C:/Ruby193/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
14:59:32 - ERROR - Invalid Guardfile, original error is:
> [#] undefined method `superclass' for nil:NilClass
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:57:in `
initialize_plugin': undefined method `superclass' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodErro
r)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard.rb:167:in
 `add_plugin'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/dsl.rb:17
5:in `block in guard'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/dsl.rb:17
3:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/dsl.rb:17
3:in `guard'
        from C:/Users/Mark/Dropbox/www/trainercompare/app/Guardfile:4:in `_insta
nce_eval_guardfile'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/guardfile
/evaluator.rb:121:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/guardfile
/evaluator.rb:121:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/guardfile
/evaluator.rb:37:in `evaluate_guardfile'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/setuper.r
b:144:in `evaluate_guardfile'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/setuper.r
b:62:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/commander
.rb:24:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/lib/guard/cli.rb:96
:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/command.rb
:27:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/invocation
.rb:120:in `invoke_command'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor.rb:363:in
`dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/thor-0.18.1/lib/thor/base.rb:43
9:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/guard-2.2.4/bin/guard:6:in `<to
p (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/guard:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
```

I think the problem is that guard/phpunit is an abandoned project and has not been updated to support the latest guard.  I think this because when I delete all the gem files relating to guard 2.2.4 and leave only the files relating to guard 1.8.3 guard will run and watch the files and run phpunit once (fail which it shouldnt) and then refuse to continue watching so its not working completely but gets a step further.

1. Can anyone give me a fix?
2. I am not a rubyist but the code in guard/phpunit looks straightforward enough, can anyone give me a link to somewhere that explains how to go about making sure a plug in is compatible with guard 2.2.4?  I could then try it myself
3. any other ideas?

I am not a rubyist but the code in guard/phpunit looks straightforward enough and I am wonderin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having this problem, and it was very painful. Currently I switched to linux, thats why I am unable to test the solution. But it should work fine.

- Remove all ruby gems and ruby completely.
- Download and install ruby old version like 1.9 [rubyInstaller
  site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694997/gem-install-json-v-1-7-3-gives-please-update-your-path-to-include-build-tools?answertab=votes#tab-top) [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694997/gem-install-json-v-1-7-3-gives-please-update-your-path-to-include-build-tools?answertab=votes#tab-top): http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
- Download dev tools from that site too. [Check this answer before setup, setup like this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694997/gem-install-json-v-1-7-3-gives-please-update-your-path-to-include-build-tools?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- You will need to install for displaying messages/notifications [Growl Notifications for
  windows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx)
- gem install guard-phpunit (it will automatically install its dependent guard version)
- gem install ruby_gntp
- run 'guard' command form your web app directory via cmd, and growl notification software in windows background
- to run all test press enter, first time when you will run test from guard you will get allCompletlyImplemented() error on ResultPrinter.php file, in cmd you will get the file location.  Replace all occurrences of  allCompletlyImplemented() to allCompletelyImplemented() in that file

--Notes:

- to exit from guard simply press e and enter.
- [My guard file, borrowed from my mentor Jeffry Way's guard tool](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82391191/Guardfile)

Hope it works. Finger crossed.

Answer (score 1):

> I think the problem is that guard/phpunit is an abandoned project and has not been updated to support the latest guard.

There's no need to upgrade a Guard plugin for the latest Guard version, since the changes are backward compatible.

In general you need to install [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) for managing your gems and setup the load path for the application to find the dependent gems. So if you have e.g. the following in your `Gemfile`

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'guard-phpunit'
```

then you can install Guard and Guard::PhpUnit with

```
bundle exec guard
```

Also, did you see that there is an [active fork](https://github.com/ramon/guard-phpunit2) that is released as `guard-phpunit2`?

Comment: Thank you I just checked out and installed guard-phpunit2 and am getting the same error so I guess that rules out that as the cause I will have to take a look at how everything is set up over the weekend when I have time to try and hunt down the cause because I am already getting burnt out switching to the cmd line every save :p

Comment: I just ran into this problem this morning and `guard-phpunit2` was the fix.  You also need to change your `Guardfile` to reflect the change from `phpunit` to `phpunit2`.  Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.
I use guard-phpunit2 with this Guardfile

```
guard 'phpunit2', :cli => '--colors', :tests_path => 'tests', :command => "./vendor/bin/phpunit" do
  watch(%r{^.+Test\.php$})
end
```

Now work OK