# Problems relating to installing Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used the below link to solve the problem. But got few other problems.

[gem install json -v 1.7.3 gives 'Please update your PATH to include build tools'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694997/gem-install-json-v-1-7-3-gives-please-update-your-path-to-include-build-tools)

```
`enter code here`C:\>ruby dk.rb init
[INFO] found RubyInstaller v2.2.4 at C:/Ruby22
```

Initialization complete! Please review and modify the auto-generated
'config.yml' file to ensure it contains the root directories to all
of the installed Rubies you want enhanced by the DevKit.

I don't know what changes I am supposed to make and how.

```
C:\>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Updating convenience notice gem override for 'C:/Ruby22'
[INFO] Installing 'C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/site_ruby/devkit.rb'

C:\>gem install rdiscoun
t --platform=ruby
Fetching: rdiscount-2.1.8.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rdiscount:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20160313-1220-1i9eix7.rb extconf.rb
checking for random()... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Provided configuration options:

```
       --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby22/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
        --with-rdiscount-dir
        --without-rdiscount-dir
        --with-rdiscount-include
        --without-rdiscount-include=${rdiscount-dir}/include
        --with-rdiscount-lib
        --without-rdiscount-lib=${rdiscount-dir}/lib
C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generat
e an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:556:in `try_link'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:735:in `try_func'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1020:in `block in have_func'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:911:in `block in checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block (2 levels) in postpo
ne'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:351:in `block in postpone'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:321:in `open'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:347:in `postpone'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:910:in `checking_for'
        from C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:1019:in `have_func'
        from extconf.rb:5:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rdiscount-
2.1.8 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.2.0/rdi
scount-2.1.8/gem_make.out
```

Can you please help me with the problem. I've been trying solve this problem for a month. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have already installed DevKit, so the error message

> You have to install development tools first.

suggests you have a mismatch between your Ruby version and your DevKit version.  Ensure both are 64bit, or both are 32bit versions, and that you choose whichever matches your operating system.